# How to transform a String "JUN 28, 2022" in another string "06-28-2022"

Tags: java, string, date

For JAVA: I need a method that takes a date with the month in letters like "January" or "JAN" and finds it's correspondent "01".

Can you give me any ideas?

Comment: My idea would be to take a look at the java.time classes, and learn the basics of parsing and formatting with those classes: [Java string to date conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion)

Comment: if you have a String like `January`, then you can do `Month.valueOf("January".toUpperCase()).getValue()` to get the numeric value